# Custom post type code hides navigation

Tags: custom-post-types

Hi I have this code for custom post types

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );

 function my_get_posts( $query ) {
if ( is_home() )
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'album', 'movie', 'quote', 'attachment' ) );

return $query;
}
```

i added it to my functions.php file, it works but it makes my navigation menu disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution, and it does more than what i asked. This solution shows the custom post types that you want to appear on the homepage and the second half shows it in the archives and search results :)

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );

function my_get_posts( $query ) {

    if ( is_home() && false == $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] || is_feed() )
            $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'posts', 'custom_post_type_name' ) );

    return $query;
 }

 add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'query_post_type');
 function query_post_type($query) {
 if ( is_archive() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {
$post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
    if($post_type)
        $post_type = $post_type;
    else
        $post_type = array('posts', 'custom_post_type_name');
$query->set('post_type',$post_type);
    return $query;
}
}
```

Place this in your functions.php file

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're overwriting the nav menu query. By adding the `! is_admin()` and `$query->is_main_query()` conditionals, you can ensure that you're targeting the main query for posts on the front end.

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );
function my_get_posts( $query ) {

 if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_home() )
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'album', 'movie', 'quote', 'attachment' ) );

return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason the query was hiding navigation is because you were missing the 'nav_menu_items' post type:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_pre' );
function filter_pre( $query ) {
    if( ! $query->is_main_query() || ! $query->is_home() )
        return $query;
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'posts', 'custom_p_type', 'nav_menu_items' ) );

    return $query;
 }
```